# I am trying to install Linux Ubuntu on my PC and I get unknown chipset errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to install Linux Ubuntu from a DVD. However, I'm getting the following errors...

[image]
[[image: Picture of location of clusters]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdRhz.png)

How can I just install Ubuntu on my PC? I don't understand why this is so difficult.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu exactly?  Update your question.

Comment: It's version 14.02.

Comment: Are you trying to install the 32-bit or 64-bit version?  You are sure its 14.02 and not 14.04.2?  Please update your question.

Comment: 64 bit version and it's 14.04.2 my bad.

Comment: Update your question with that very relevant information.  What CPU do you have?   Please include that information in your question.

Comment: This appears to be connected to your GPU.  [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/598417/nouveau-unknown-chipset-on-installer) is a work around

Comment: The GPU issue is nothing compared to the SATA issue.  You might have to change which port your DVD drive is connected to.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/228927/boot-failure-failed-command-identify-packet-device and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=174335.

You could/should also try installing from USB.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to re- install the Ubuntu and this time from another dvd or usb flash drive.Also try using the Linuxmint versions as it already has all the necessary drivers required to run a system. Linuxmint versions are little bit BIG in file size but they are worth it.